# node_presave doesn't work

Tags: nodes, users, theming

I'm trying to do something before my invoice saves. In my invoice module I have:

```
function invoice_node_presave($node) {
  var_dump($node); die;
  if ($node->type == 'invoice') {
    // If true we are creating a new invoice
    if (intval($node->invoice_number) == 0) {
      // Get new invoice number
      if (intval($node->user_defined_invoice_number) > 0) {
        $node->invoice_number = $node->user_defined_invoice_number;
      }
      else {
        $node->invoice_number = _invoice_get_new_invoice_number();
      }
    }
  }
  ......
}
```

As you see I have a `var_dump($node)` & a `die;` . This works perfect. But then when I want to add the following in my `template.php` :

```
function xmed_node_presave($node){
  dump($node); die;
  if (($node->type == 'invoice')) { //node has not been saved
      dpr($node); die;
  }
```

}

He doesn't die. He just runs... Also the rest of functions in my `template.php` like function `xmed_preprocess_page(&$vars)` work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see below code in node.module node_save() function..

```
module_invoke_all('node_presave', $node);
```

It's only invoked if you implement it in modules..

- Create a folder called 'custom' in sites/all/modules
- Create a folder called 'mynodeactions' in above custom folder
- Create a file called mynodeaactions.info inside above folder with

below code

```
name = My Node Actions
description = A custom module to tackle different node actions
core = 7.x
package = Custom
```

- Create a file called mynodeactions.module inside 'mynodeactions' folder with

below code

```
<?php

function mynodeactions_node_presave($node){

}

?>
```

For more information See the [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7) if you're not sure

Comment: And how can I do this? Maybe a link to tutorial or something?

Comment: You just need to put your `xmed_node_presave()` function in a module instead of template.php

Comment: See updated detailed answer...

Answer (score 4):

`hook_node_presave()` is only invoked for modules, so you can't implement it in a theme.

It'll need to go in a custom module instead.

From a best practice point of view, that sort of logic definitely shouldn't be at the theme layer, it should be in a module.

Comment: And how can I do this? Maybe a link to tutorial or something?

Comment: How can you do what? Implement a hook or write a module? It's funny that you ask, since the code in your question is already doing both :) See the [module developer's guide](https://drupal.org/developing/modules) if you're not sure

Comment: The problem is I don't now where to place my code :P Another question, It's bad practice to overwrite the standard invoice module in the code of the invoice module I guess?

Comment: You guess correctly :) If you can possibly help it, always write a new module to alter existing functionality, rather than editing core/contrib modules directly. It makes life so much easier when you come to updating

Comment: Ok, now I just need to learn how to create a module so I can alter my basic invoice module.

Comment: Anil's added a short example to his answer, that should get you going