# hook_node_update not working

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I placed the following function in my custom module.

```
function MYMODULE_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type === 'page') {
    $node->title = 'test';
  }
}
```

When editing and saving a node of content type page nothing happens. What can be the issue?

---

Problem solved. It seemed to be caused by the following:

my custom module wasn't ending with ?> and above all my module name was custom_site.module and my hooks started with custom. This didn't give problems before with my other hooks so I never noticed. (This helped: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/111272/85560)

My module name now is custom.module and now custom_node_presave() works.

Comment: `node_save($node);` right after `$node->title = 'test';`. And flush cache. But maybe better rely on [`hook_node_insert`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7.x). Not sure.

Comment: No need to call node_save() in a hook_node_update() as the hook is invoked from the node_save function itself. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x

Comment: The hook name would be `custom_site_` and not `custom_`. I would advise devising a better naming strategy.

Comment: Add your question update as answer so other can benefict from your findings. Thanks!

Comment: I am actually already using another more identic name for custom. I just used it as an example.

My module name is MYMODULE.module and the hook name is MYMODULE_node_presave().

Answer (score 2):

You should use [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) if you want to change a field's value as the hook is invoked from node_save() before the node is saved to the database. And as leymannx stated, make sure you clear the cache before implementing a new hook.